# POST method in Google Apps Script

Tags: ajax, json, google-apps-script, http-post

May I ask what is wrong when I use the POST method in the Apps script?

```
function myFunctionpost() {
  var url = "mydomain.com/2spreadsheet.php";
  var data = { "testpost" :　" Text text text" };
   var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

 var headers = { "Accept":"application/json", 
                "contentType" : "application/json",
              "Authorization":"Basic _authcode_"
             };

 var options = { "method":"POST",
             "contentType" : "application/json",
            "headers": headers,
                "payload" : payload
           };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url ,options);
  Logger.log(response );  
 }
```

The ***myFunctionpost()*** in the Apps script is about posting the Json data : "testpost" to the url.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo "Server is requested";

    if(isset($_POST["testpost"])){
      echo "Post something here";
      echo $_POST["testpost"];
    }
}
```

And the code in (***2spreadsheet.php***) showing that I want to post the data I posted, but it does not work.

The Loggin Output:

> [15-07-12 14:06:00:205 HKT]
>
> Server is requested

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to specify the content type and can leave out JSON.Stringify. Your object data is already a JavaScript object. It will be interpreted as an HTML form.

```
var url = "mydomain.com/2spreadsheet.php";
var data = { "testpost" :　" Text text text" };

var options = { "method":"POST",
                "payload" : data
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url ,options);
Logger.log(response );
```

The content type will default to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. You can check this with $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"].